# Pandas optimization

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I wrote a function to process data with pandas. Profiling log using `%prun` of my function is posted at bottom (only a top few lines). I want to optimize my code because I need call this function I wrote more than 4,000 times. And it took 37.7 s to run this function once.

It seems the most time consuming part is `nonzero` of `numpy.ndarray`. Since almost all of my operations are based on `pandas`, I wonder which function in `pandas` rely on this method heavily?

My operations are mostly consisted by dataframe slicing based on `datetimeindex` using `df.ix[]` and dataframe merges using `pandas.merge()`.

I know it's hard to tell without posting my actual script, but the script is too long to be meaningful and most operations are ad hoc, so i can't rewrite it into small script to post it here.

```
         16439731 function calls (16108083 primitive calls) in 37.766 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     7461    3.712    0.000    3.712    0.000 {method 'nonzero' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
      244    1.731    0.007    5.434    0.022 index.py:1126(_partial_date_slice)
      122    1.655    0.014    1.655    0.014 {pandas.algos.inner_join_indexer_int64}
      610    1.578    0.003    1.578    0.003 {method 'factorize' of 'pandas.hashtable.Int64Factorizer' objects}
   118817    0.764    0.000    0.764    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
    22474    0.753    0.000    0.917    0.000 index.py:409(is_unique)
   353210    0.669    0.000    1.228    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
  1577935    0.596    0.000    0.925    0.000 {isinstance}
     1221    0.511    0.000    0.516    0.000 index.py:402(is_monotonic)
      183    0.427    0.002    0.427    0.002 {pandas.algos.left_outer_join}
    34529    0.376    0.000    1.286    0.000 index.py:98(__new__)
    12356    0.358    0.000    0.358    0.000 {method 'take' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
     3812    0.352    0.000    0.352    0.000 {pandas.algos.take_2d_axis0_int64_int64}
      610    0.344    0.001    0.349    0.001 index.py:35(wrapper)
      981    0.334    0.000    0.335    0.000 {method 'copy' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
```

Comment: **Always** err on the side of too much information, rather than too little, @user3576212

Comment: it looks like you are doing some sort of iteration then indexing, which in general is not an efficient way of selecting values; show your code otherwise you will only get guesses (if that)

Comment: @Jeff Yes, it's indeed the case. I am looping over the index of dataframe. Then use extracted index to slice another dataframe. Because these are irregular operations, I can't use merge/join. Let me see if I can come up with a shorter code to illustrate my purpose. In the meantime, do you know which `pandas` function rely heavily on `nonzero` method in `numpy`?Thanks!

Comment: practially all indexing functions use ``nonzero``, which btw is one of the most heavility optimized functions. You should not be looping.

Comment: @Jeff I just find out the most time consuming part of my code is `df.ix[begin_date:end_date]`. The dataframe `df` is index by timestamps, `begin_date` and `end_date` are generated from other steps to extract part of `df`. Are you aware of any faster alternative than `df.ix[]`? I also tried `df.query()`, but no much improvement.

Comment: you are still missing the point. if u are indexing say a small section many times that is very inefficient. but without code it is impossible to tell. you are trying to micro optimize, but you need to look at the entire problem

Comment: @Jeff thanks for your attention. Still try to break my long script into shorter pieces to post it

Comment: That would be a good idea. Also, have you sorted the index? That can make a difference

Answer (score 0):

The df.ix[] is a little unpredictable in that is primarily label-based but has an integer-position fallback. You should try using .loc[] instead. If you just pass a single label it will return a series of the row at that index label. You can also slice by passing a range. So instead of:

```
df.ix[begin_date:end_date]
```

Try:

```
df.loc[begin_date:end_date]
```

Even faster would be to use the integer-based slicing method .iloc[]. Since you're looping over the index anyway you could just add an enumerate() to your loop and use the enumerate() values, i.e.:

```
df.iloc[4:9]
```

On my machine .iloc tends to be about twice as fast as .loc.